# When did using digital graphics tablets for anime production instead of pencil and paper become widespread?

Tags: anime-production, anime-history

I know anime studios stopped using cels in the late 90s. But in the beginning after switching to digital, they still used to draw on paper and then scan it into the computer. But nowadays, they mostly use a digital graphics tablet to directly draw into the computer. At what year did drawing digitally into the computer become widespread?

Comment: Around the time these things became cheaper than the alternative. Probably around 2007 plus a couple of years for everyone to catch on. Except for Ghibli, of course, they still draw on paper. Wouldn't be surprised if they aren't the only ones..